# Проблема с загрузкой шаблона на хостинг

Tags: сервер, joomla, opencart, веб-сервер

Скачал шаблон для интернет магазина.В `index.html` такое вот сообщение:

```
This is a technical file included in your template package for security reasons.

Please refer to technical documentation for the correct path to your template index file.
```

Так же в папках файла есть `info.txt` где есть следующее обращение:

```
For security reasons the directory containing all the source files of the template (\"SOURCES_XXXXXXXX\")is in a compressed (zipped) file and password protected. 
To uncompress (unzip) a password protected ZIP file you will need to have a zip file utility program installed and a password. As soon as the zip file begins to uncompress, you will be prompted to type in a password .
The password is the Transaction ID number of your order (a long number with letters and digits). 
You can find this number on the order page which will be provided to you through a link that we sent to you via email.
Please help us to preserve the quality and uniqueness of our products by not uploading \"SOURCES_XXXXXXXX\" directories either zipped or unzipped to the server.
```

Не понимаю, что нужно делать?

Comment: Здесь написано что делать, какое слово вам непонятно?

Comment: Распарольте любым архиватором; где взять пароль — про это здесь тоже написано

Comment: это был бесплатный шаблон, я без проблем разархивировал его в папке есть основные файлы и info.txt  никаких паролей я не нашел

Comment: http://psdsite.ru/russkiy-oscommerce-shablon-psd-v-komplekte.html

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

В сообщении указано, что нужно *"исправить путь до файла index"*.
Попробуйте загрузить файлы по отдельности: сначала только *index.html*, потом проверить результат и загрузить всё остальное.

Answer (score 0):

На хостинг Вам нужно загрузить из архива только содержимое каталога osc/catalog. Это дистрибутив **osCommerce** с интегрированным шаблоном. [Инструкция](http://www.oscommerce.ru/documentation/oscommerce-v-2-3/pervie-shagi/ustanovka-na-hosting.html) по установке osCommerce на хостинг. После этого надо будет импортировать в БД дамп из архива sources/dump.sql